# htdocs mage.php was not found

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, core-file-storage

I got error into my Magento website.

> /homepages/26/d589154144/htdocs//app/Mage.php was not found

I have searched this on many places not get the exact solution.

Please help to solve. Thanks.

Comment: but the file is there? and it is readable?

Comment: The // may be your issue. Try and eliminate that.